# Bluetooth Connection failed: Software caused connection abort

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, lts, bluez

I got a new laptop and installed ubuntu 20.04 as I had on my previous laptop. Everything went smoothly and I could connect my Airpods. One morning I just couldn't and I've got this error since.
I've tried uninstalling bluetooth manager and bluez, installing again but I get the same error.
I see other people had the same problem, but the solution doesn't seem to be there.

e.g. [Ubuntu 20.04 LTS bluetooth connection failed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1254404/ubuntu-20-04-lts-bluetooth-connection-failed)
This is the problem I have, and using bluetooth from the system doesn't help.

All help will be appreciated, I don't know what to do at this point.